# Why is Bootstraps "Modal" Plugin callback not firing?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm having a problem understanding Bootstraps Modal **Callbacks**.

The "*.on('show',function(){})*" portion of the following code is not firing. Not sure why. Please advise. Also, any/all code optimization tips welcome.

**The HTML**

```
<p><a class="bsModal" href="#" title="Bootstrap Modal">testing modal</a></p>
```

**The jQuery**

```
    // Dynamically calling Bootstrap Modal
$('.bsModal').click(function(){


    var bsModalWindow = '<div class="modal" id="myModal">';
        bsModalWindow +=    '<div class="modal-header">';
        bsModalWindow +=        '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>';
        bsModalWindow +=            '<h3>Modal header</h3>';
        bsModalWindow +=    '</div>';
        bsModalWindow +=    '<div class="modal-body">';
        bsModalWindow +=        '<p>This is an example of the Bootstrap jQuery Plugin: Modal.</p>';
        bsModalWindow +=    '</div>';
        bsModalWindow +=    '<div class="modal-footer">';
        bsModalWindow +=        '<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>';
        bsModalWindow +=        '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>';
        bsModalWindow +=    '</div>';
        bsModalWindow += '</div>';

        $(bsModalWindow).modal()
            .on('show', function() {
                console.log('Modal will be shown');
            })
            .on('shown', function() {
                console.log('Modal was shown');
            })
            .on('hide', function() {
                console.log('Modal will be hidden');
            })
            .on('hidden', function() {
                console.log('Modal is hidden');
            })
            .show({
                backdrop: true,
                keyboard:true
            });                 

});
```

Comment: Fiddle for this http://jsfiddle.net/D2RLR/728/

Comment: @sabithpocker. I see your fiddle but again, the first callback on('show', function...) is not firing. All others are firing. Try changing it to an alert to see the problem.

Comment: it's not solved, just converted this to fiddle so that everyone can take a look ..

Comment: @sleeper Try to use .trigger() like this: `.show({backdrop: true,keyboard:true}).trigger('show').trigger('shown')`, in the above fiddle seem to work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is your solution for displaying dynamic bootstrap model and call its callback function.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <div class="divbutton">
    <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-primary btn-large bsModal">
      Launch Demo Modal 
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var bsModalWindow = '<div class="modal hidden fade" id="myModal">';
    bsModalWindow += '<div class="modal-header">';
    bsModalWindow += '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Ã�</button>';
    bsModalWindow += '<h3>Modal header</h3>';
    bsModalWindow += '</div>';
    bsModalWindow += '<div class="modal-body">';
    bsModalWindow += '<p>This is an example of the Bootstrap jQuery Plugin: Modal.</p>';
    bsModalWindow += '</div>';
    bsModalWindow += '<div class="modal-footer">';
    bsModalWindow += '<a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Close</a>';
    bsModalWindow += '<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</a>';
    bsModalWindow += '</div>';
    bsModalWindow += '</div>';

    //Append Model Div before button div on html page
    $(".divbutton").before(bsModalWindow); 

    $(".bsModal").click(function() {
        //Bind Callback functions with model events 
        $("#myModal").on('show', function() {
            //Change Top position of modal on show call back
            $("#myModal").css('top', '100%');
            console.log('Modal will be shown');
        }).on('shown', function() {
            console.log('Modal was shown');
        }).on('hide', function() {
            console.log('Modal will be hidden');
        }).on('hidden', function() {
            console.log('Modal is hidden');
        }).show({
            backdrop: true,
            keyboard: true
        });
        //Show Modal
        $("#myModal").modal('show');
    });
});
```

I have done bins on http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqpa7

Comment: Thanks guys sorry I took so long, but I've been sick. I'm checking the responses now and will select an answer shortly.

Comment: that did it. Thanks! Plus codebin is pretty cool. Will check it out.